# Свой скриптовый язык

Tags: java, ооп, скрипт

Я придумал очень интересный проект на java, но мне надо реализовать свой язык, в котором не так много будет пока функций. В интернете мало об этом написано. С чего начать и как это можно реализовать?
Вот у меня есть JTextField и я пишу туда create rectangle (1,1,60,60), а где - то в коде создаётся объект, плюс хорошо бы его функции из скрипта вызывать, но пока не могу сообразить как

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, а чем не угодил lua?

Comment: Marat, не извиняем

Comment: Если задача прямо так и стоит - свой язык, то ничего не скажу, Не может быть в интернете совсем ничего. Но если что, java уже давно поставляется с движком javascript

Comment: Мне нужны собственные функции и чтобы через этот язык я мог обращаться к объектам, просто измененная удобная запись. Я не знаю можно ли реализовать такое через lua

Comment: @Sergey, Javascript в данном случае будет неудобен

Comment: Возьмите Groovy и запилите на нем DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Интернете очень много об это написано. Посмотрите по теме DSL - Domain Specific Language. Если Вы уж на java, то посмотрите в сторону Scala - это язык на базе JVM, в котором создание своих DSL уделили значительную роль.

Кроме того, для java есть куча проектов, реализующих скриптовые языки. Например :

- http://www.beanshell.org/
- http://www.jython.org/
- http://www.groovy-lang.org/

Comment: Хорошо посмотрю завтра, надеюсь это оправдает мои ожидания. Обязательно отпишу